# How to set max value dependent on other fields in Angular Formly?

Tags: json, angular, angular-formly

I have two fields, e.g. `x` and `y`. I want the third field to have max value set to sum of the others. How to achieve this? `max` option doesn't work with this expression

```
{
            "className": "col col-2",
            "type": "round",
            "defaultValue": 0,
            "key": "z",
            "templateOptions": {
              "label": "110. ",
              "max": "x+y"
            }
}
```